# What are commercial impact models and transaction cost analysis models out there for simulation?

Tags: simulations, transaction-costs, market-impact, slippage

I have heard that ITG, LiquidMetrix, MarkIT and TradingScreen has good Transaction Cost Analysis (TCA) research. I wonder which firm one would choose to have an impact model formula inside his simulations (that is to optimize traded portfolio size).

There are two ways to achive this:

- find a firm which discloses their complete impact model
- find a firm which provides a detailed simulator including the impact models

Open for suggestions for both options.